# how to call function after append html to the directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

viewBannerCtrl is the controller in that i'm using "customTable" directive 
Here i'm not able to access "VBC.bannerAlert()" function from the directive 
and i appended the code to directive but not able to access controller functions with append tag

```js
 

.controller('viewBannerCtrl',function(){
    vbc.bannerAlert = function(){
      alert('success called in inside directive.....Hurry!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    };

});
.directive('customTable', function customTable($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'app/admin/modules/common/views/custom_table.html',
            scope: {
                data: '=data',
                dataLength: '=datalength',
                filterDataArray: '=filterData',
                imageData: '=imageData'
            },
            controller: customTableCtrl,
            link:function(scope,element,attr){
var el =   angular.element(document.getElementById('dyanamicActions'));

                el.append('<button  class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-ef btn-ef-5 btn-ef-5b" ng-click="VBC.bannerAlert()"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <span>Deletess</span></button>');
                $compile(el)(scope);
            },
            controllerAs: 'CTC',
            bindToController: true
        };
    });
    function customTableCtrl(MainService) {
    var ctc = this;
    };
}
```

```html
<div custom-table data="VBC.getBannerlistData"  datalength="VBC.totalItems"
                         table-headers="VBC.tableInit" image-data="'image'"
                         table-actions="VBC.editData" delete-model="VBC.openBannerDeleteModal">

                        
                    </div>
```

Comment: You could create fiddle for this

Answer (score 0):

You current directive has implemented using isolated scope like `scope: { ... }`. So directive don't have outer scope methods are available in it(didn't follow prototypal inheritance when scope are isolated).

You have to pass `bannerAlert` function expression to directive from its isolated scope using `&`. So that that function will get available inside directive scope.

For passing that function to directive you have to write attribute `bannerAlert="bannerAlert()"` on directive element. Like I've shown below.

**Markup**

```
<div custom-table data="VBC.getBannerlistData"  
  datalength="VBC.totalItems"
  table-headers="VBC.tableInit" 
  image-data="'image'"
  table-actions="VBC.editData" 
  delete-model="VBC.openBannerDeleteModal"
  bannerAlert="bannerAlert()">
</div>
```

**Code**

```
scope: {
    data: '=data',
    dataLength: '=datalength',
    filterDataArray: '=filterData',
    imageData: '=imageData',
    bannerAlert: '&bannerAlert' //<--added expression binding here
},
```