# Angular directive injecting DOM element with click event

Tags: angularjs, directive, insertafter

#### Content edited

The goal is to create a directive that can be attached to a textbox that, when the textbox has focus, an image/button will appear after the textbox and the image/button click event will fire a function contained within the directive.  The goal is for this functionality to be entirely self-contained in the directive so it can be easily deployed in many pages or apps.

The image/button appears after the textbox with no problem but the click event of the button does not fire the function.  I have created a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IE4DjeuhCBsWRCalc5A5?p=preview) with the example code.

In the plunk, line 15 defines a function called 'search,' which does nothing more than fire an alert.  When the textbox has focus, the button appears as expected and line 34 calls the search function successfully, which means the function itself is working. However, the button's click event doesn't fire the search function.

---

#### Original post

I'm trying to recreate some functionality in our apps that is currently being accomplished with jQuery.  The functionality involves attaching a pseudo-class to a textbox which is then picked up by jQuery and an image of a magnifying glass is injected into the DOM immediately after the textbox.  Clicking on the image causes a dialog box to pop open.

What I've accomplished so far is a simple html page, a simple controller, and a simple directive.  When the textbox has focus, the image appears as expected.  However, the ng-click directive does not fire.

Here's the html:

```
            <input 
                id="txtAlias" 
                type="text" 
                ng-model="pc.results"
                user-search  />

</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
angular
   .module('app')
   .controller('PeopleController', PeopleController);

PeopleController.$inject = ['$http'];

function PeopleController() {

   var pc = this;

   pc.results = '';

   pc.search = function () {
       alert('test');
   };
}
```

And this is the directive:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('userSearch', userSearch);

function userSearch($compile) {

return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    //transclude: true,
    scope: {
        //search : function(callerid){
        //    alert(callerid);
        //}
    },
    template: "The user's alias is: <b><span ng-bind='pc.results'></span>.",
    //controller: UserSearchController,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('focus', function () {

            //alert(attrs.id + ' || ' + attrs.userSearch);

            var nextElement = element.parent().find('.openuserdialog').length;

            if (nextElement == 0) {
                var magnifyingglass = $compile('<img src="' + homePath + 'Images/zoomHS.png" ' +
                                        'alt="User Search" ' +
                                        'ng-click="pc.search("' + attrs.id + '")" ' +
                                        'class="openuserdialog">')(scope);

                element.after(magnifyingglass);
            }

        });
    }

};

};
```

For the time being, I'd be happy to get an alert to fire by either hitting pc.search in the controller or by search in the isolated scope.  So far, neither has worked.  I'm sure it's something simple that's missing but I can't figure out what.

---

#### Solution

Thanks to a user over at the Google forum for showing me the controllerAs property for directives.  This version now works perfectly:

```
angular
.module('app')
.directive('userSearch', userSearch);

function userSearch($compile){

return {
    controller: function ()
        {
            this.search = function () {
                alert('Test');
            };
        },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        element.bind('focus', function () {

            var nextElement = element.parent().find('.openuserdialog').length;

            if (nextElement === 0) {

                var btn = '<img src="' + homePath + 'Images/zoomHS.png" ' +
                            'ng-click="userSearch.search()" ' +
                            'class="openuserdialog" />';

                element.after($compile(btn)(scope));

            }

        });
    },
    controllerAs: 'userSearch'

};

};
```

Comment: If the magnifying glass icon is always there, why not just make it part of the directive's template, instead of inserting it immediately after?

Comment: @Dave, it isn't always going to be there.  The intention is that the developer will be able to add the user-search directive to whatever textbox might require the lookup feature.

Comment: Ah, and because it's a texbox, you have to put the magnifying glass outside it.  Have you considered creating a directive that always displays a texbox, and conditionally displays the magnifying glass if the the user-search attribute is present?

Comment: @Dave, getting the textbox and the magnifying glass/button to appear isn't a problem.  The stumbling block is getting the magnifying glass/button to fire a function contained within the same directive.  Editing the content above to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using isolated scope in your directive which means it don't have access to its parent scope. So in this case you need to pass your method reference explicitly to directive. Passed method reference to your directive scope by new variable inside a isolated scope of directive.

**Markup**

```
<input id="txtAlias" 
   type="text" ng-model="pc.results" 
   user-search search="search(id)" />

scope: {
   search: '&'
}
```

As you don't have access to parent scope, you can't use controller alias over there like you are using `pc.`. Simply do use following without alias. So directive will bind those variables from directive scope directly.

```
template: "The user's alias is: <b><span ng-bind='results'></span>.",
```

Also change compile template to

```
if (nextElement == 0) {
    var magnifyingglass = $compile('<img src="' + homePath + 'Images/zoomHS.png" ' +
      'alt="User Search" ' +
      'ng-click="search({id: ' + attrs.id + '})' +
      'class="openuserdialog">')(scope);
    element.after(magnifyingglass);
 }
```

Rather I'd love to have the compiled template as part of `template` of directive function only. And I'll show and hide it based on `ng-if="expression"` directive.

[**Relative answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35629018/2435473)

Comment: Thanks, Pankaj.  I altered the scope property as you suggested and changed the image's ng-click value.  No change.  The image appears but nothing happens when clicking on it.  Ultimately, clicking on the image should fire a separate function.  For now, it will be fine if the function is just an alert.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @johneasley that was my bad.. look at updated answer

Comment: Okay, scope and the ng-click property were modified as you suggested.  No change.  Still no function or alert firing when clicking the image.  The rendered html shows the following in the image control:

Comment: Okay, scope and the ng-click property were modified as you suggested.  No change.  Still no function or alert firing when clicking the image.  The rendered html shows the following in the image control:  
    ng-click="search(" txtalias}")"=""
That's certainly not right.  The goal is to have the image call a function, preferably in isolated scope.
@Pankaj Parkar

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to inject into the DOM, and then trying to hook up to that thing you just injected, wrap both the input and the search button/icon in a directive.  You can use an isolated scope and two-way binding to hook up both the input and the button:

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <search-box data="name" search-function="search"></search-box>
  </body>
```

Here's both a controller and a directive that demonstrate this.  Note the "=" in the isolated scope, creating a two-way binding to the corresponding attributes when the directive is used in a template.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.search= function() { alert('search clicked'); }
});

app.directive('searchBox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      searchFunction: '=',
      data: '=',
    },
    template: '<input ng-model="data" /><button ng-click="searchFunction()">Search</button>'
  }
})
```

You should be able to easily replace the `button` element with an `img` or whatever else your heart desires.

Here's a plunk with an alert() for the search box, and where typing in the text box in the directive affects the corresponding property of the controller scope:
http://plnkr.co/edit/0lj4AmjOgwNZ2DJMSHDj